# Каждый элемент массива в нижний регистр

Tags: javascript, jquery

Отдельный элемент переводит, в цикле не идет. Где ошибка?

```js
var tovar = [
  'Green Guatemala',
  'Negro Marquina',
  'Ouro Negro TP',
  'Rojo Alicante',
  'Rosso Levanto TP',
  'Ruivina',
  'Travertino Noce',
  'Travertino Wallnut',
  'Volacas'
];

alert(tovar[1].toLowerCase()); // работает

var sql = "";
for (var i = 0; i <= tovar.length; i++) {
  var toLowerCase = tovar[i].toLowerCase();
  sql = sql + " =" + i + " " + toLowerCase;
}
alert(sql);
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас классическая ошибка [off-by-one](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%83). В условии цикла должно быть не `<=`, а `<`, так как в вашем случае вы выходите за границу массива.

Answer (score 2):

Впринципе тут все было правильно, только возникала ошибка изза не совсем верного построения цикла.
Индексаторы начинаються с 0, а в изначальном цикле было  i <= tovar.length;, что давало на последней итерации цикла undefined, к которому была попытка применить метод toLowerCase(), изза чего собственно и была ошибка.
Тоесть, в таких случаях надо ставить либо < либо tovar.length -1, как-то так :)

```js
var tovar=[
 'Green Guatemala',
 'Negro Marquina',
 'Ouro Negro TP',
 'Rojo Alicante',
 'Rosso Levanto TP',
 'Ruivina',
 'Travertino Noce',
 'Travertino Wallnut',
 'Volacas'
 ];

  var sql="";
  for(var i = 0; i < tovar.length; i++)
  {
    var toLowerCase = tovar[i].toLowerCase(); 
    sql=sql+" ="+i+" "+toLowerCase;
  }
  console.log(sql);
```

Comment: Если честно второе "либо" как-то не комильфо

Comment: ну так-то да, но возможность такова существует